# Dealing with Instagram APIs (JSON + PHP)

Tags: php, json, api, instagram

I'm new to PHP and I can't figure out how to deal with Instagram APIs in order to (for example) extract a list of links to the standard resolution images by recent 3 items published by the user_id 3.

Here's what I created till now:

```
<?php
function get_instagram($user_id,$count)
{
    $user_id = '3';
    $count = '3';
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?access_token=13137.f59def8.1a759775695548999504c219ce7b2ecf&count='.$count;
    $jsonData = $json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
    $data = $jsonData->data;
    $result = '<ul>';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $result .= '<li><a href='.$value->link.' ><img src="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'" width="70" height="70" /></a></li> ';
    }
    $result .= '</ul>';
    return $result;
}
```

The result is a blank page though.. can you help me?

Comment: You're `return`ing the result. If you want it to show up on page, you need to `echo` it. (`echo $result;`)

Comment: Thanks nav_nav, I changed that! Anyway the page is still blank.. Maybe there is more than an error..? :(

Comment: try echoing the JSON data to see what your result is, from Instagram. `echo $jsonData;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to echo or do something with the returned data (Also you have a rouge `$` in front of your json_decode function)

**Try this:**

```
<?php
function get_instagram($user_id=15203338,$count=6,$width=190,$height=190){

    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?access_token=13137.f59def8.1a759775695548999504c219ce7b2ecf&count='.$count;

    // Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
    $cache = './'.sha1($url).'.json';
    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
        // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    } else {
        $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
    }

    $result = '<div id="instagram">'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
        $result .= "\t".'<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" 
                            title="'.htmlentities($value->caption->text).' '.htmlentities(date("F j, Y, g:i a", $value->caption->created_time)).'"
                            style="padding:3px" href="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'">
                          <img src="'.$value->images->low_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$value->caption->text.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" />
                          </a>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $result .= '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    return $result;
}

echo get_instagram();
?>
```

---

With `$value->location->name`

If you want to check its empty and if it is then dont show it but also want to append a string onto it if it is set you would do something like:

```
$location = (!empty($value->location->name))?'@'.$value->location->name:null;
```

Then use `$location` to echo where you want it.

Comment: @multiformeinggno ive added a basic cache to it as the API can be slow and if results dont change often there's no need to load fresh content on each page load. ;)

Comment: Latest question.. This is my code now (added Fancybox and other stuff): http://pastebin.com/9FaxTx0y

How do I transform the unix timestamp echoed by "created_time" in "normal" PHP dates? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: nice, to convert a timestamp use the date() function something like `date("F j, Y, g:i a", TIMESTAMPVALUE);` check it out at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Great! :)

I'm trying to use it here:
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="'.$value->caption->text.' '.date("F j, Y, g:i a", $value->caption->created_time);'" style="padding:3px" href="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'"><img src="'.$value->images->low_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$value->caption->text.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a>

It "works" (I can see the correct date in source html) but it breaks the code i.e. the source code ends after the title="" tag, so there's probably an error (I'm missing a dot or something else..?).

Comment: Another question (don't kill me.. :P):

How can I have something like "@ location name" if location exist?
I'm using this: '.$value->location->name.' and it shows up if location exist, how do I add "@" before location name IF location exist? :)

Comment: ive updated the answer to include your edits, you need to use htmlentities() function to encode chars that wont break your output. not sure what you mean bout @ location name, you can put `@` in front of any variable to suppress an undefined error or such

Comment: Thanks!! :D
For @ I mean AT. For example if the photo has a location "San Francisco", it would be nice to have something like "CAPTION at/@ LOCATION". :)
The problem is that I don't want to display AT if location data is empty..

Comment: Now everything works perfectly!! :D
The only thing that annoys a bit is that with htmlentities() I have accents broken. For example ì becomes Ã~ ... char-set page is UTF8

Comment: Is this code correct? :)
'.htmlentities($value->caption->text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'

Comment: I want to overdo.. :P
Is this other piece of code correct (I didn't try)?

$cache = bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');'./instagram_json/'.sha1($url).'.json';

I'd like to store the JSON cache files in my Wordpress theme directory/instagram_json/ so I'm calling the bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); function to get the directory..

Answer (score 2):

I've extended the selected answer by writing a small script that can be used a boilerplate for anyone trying this.

It's setup with all the variables and starts with basic markup. Using selectors from Instagrams API docs you can build onto its output as needed.

This is built to be used specifically with WordPress with one small tweak to the image size conditional it can be used in any PHP application.

```
<?php
function instagram($count = 10, $width = 640, $height = 640) {

    $user_id = 123456789;
    $access_token = '123456789';
    $size = wp_is_mobile() ? 'low_resolution' : 'standard_resolution';
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?access_token='.$access_token.'&count='.$count;
    $cache_location = './'.sha1($url).'.json';
    $cache_time = '-1 hour';

    if (file_exists($cache_location) && filemtime($cache_location) > strtotime($cache_time)) {
        // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache_location));
    } else {
        $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
        file_put_contents($cache_location,json_encode($jsonData));
    }

    foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<img src="'.$value->images->$size->url.'"/>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Basic Usage

```
<?php echo instagram(); ?>
```

Advanced Usage

```
<?php echo instagram($count = 1, $width = 100, $height = 100); ?>
```

[Github Repo](https://github.com/j2designpartnership/instagram-php)

Answer (score 0):

Welp, This was working a week ago, but now, it gives me a PHP error:

> "Message: Trying to get property of non-object"

on the line with the foreach statement: `foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value)`

Turns out my JSON feed was actually corrupted, the captions to some of my instagrams were missing, so I had to add an if empty statement. I also am using a different method now, curious on your thoughts, works great!

```
<?php

  function fetchData($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  return $result;
  }

  $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER ID HERE/media/recent/?access_token=ACCES TOKEN HERE&count=14");

  $cache = './instagram.json';
  if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
  // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
  $instaData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    } else {
  $instaData = json_decode((file_get_contents($result)));
    file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($instaData));
  }

  foreach ($instaData->data as $post) {
     if(empty($post->caption->text)) {
       // Do Nothing
     }
     else {
        echo '<a class="instagram-unit" target="blank" href="'.$post->link.'">
        <img src="'.$post->images->low_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$post->caption->text.'" width="100%" height="auto" />
        <div class="instagram-desc">'.htmlentities($post->caption->text).' | '.htmlentities(date("F j, Y, g:i a", $post->caption->created_time)).'</div></a>';
     }

  }
?>
```