# Instagram max requests per hour (30) exceeded?

Tags: php, api, oauth, instagram

```
{
   "code":420,
   "error_type":"OAuthRateLimitException",
   "error_message":"You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per hour. You have performed a total of 253 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum request limit is set at 30 requests per hour."
}
```

I just noticed a clients website I am looking after has stopped showing the Instagram feed, so I loaded up the feed URL straight into the browser and I got the above error. I don't think there should have been 253 requests in an hour, but whilst Googling this problem, I came across someone saying it was because the API was being logged in on every request. Sadly, I have "inherited" this code, and haven't really worked with the Instagram API before, apart from to fix an error with this same website before.

The clients site is in WordPress so I have wrapped the code to get the images in a function:

```
function get_instagram($user_id=USERID,$count=6,$width=190,$height=190){
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&count='.$count;

    // Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
    $cache = './'.sha1($url).'.json';
    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
        // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    } else {
        $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
    }
    $result = '<a style="background-image:url(/wp-content/themes/iwear/inc/img/instagram-background.jpg);" target="_BLANK" href="http://www.instagr.am" class="lc-box lcbox-4 instagram">'.PHP_EOL.'<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
        $result .= "\t".'<li><img src="'.$value->images->low_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$value->caption->text.'" data-width="'.$width.'" data-height="'.$height.'" /><div class="lc-box-inner"><div class="title"><h2>images</h2></div><div class="description">'.$value->caption->text.'</div></div></li>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $result .= '</ul></a>'.PHP_EOL;

    return $result;
}
```

But as I said, this code has stopped working. Is there any way I could optimize this to actually work? I also notice there is mention of a cache in the (probably stolen) instagram stuff, but it isn't actually caching, so that could also be a solution

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using caching the result for 1 hour on your server? maybe using memcache / memcached. Also are you using any framework with inbuilt caching or are you relying on instagram api to do the caching?

Comment: lol i thought i wrote that, just shows you can copy&paste without learning what it does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231369/dealing-with-instagram-apis-json-php , OP the result should cache for 1 hour if its not then check file permissions and that `'./'.sha1($url).'.json';` is writeable. Also you should think about moving to the v2 API

Comment: @LozCherone Indeed it does show that. I am against copypasting in general, and would rather get my head round the code to better myself, but in situations where I've been dropped in it by a previous dev, I like to be as uninvolved as possible with their solutions.

My thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3):

Try registering a new client in instagram and then change

`$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&count='.$count;`

for

`$url = https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&count='.$count;`

where CLIENT_ID is the client id of your recently created client.